# CSS Hollow out a div?

Tags: css, transparency

I have a 3 elements stacked on top of each other. The top element is the overlay content. The second element is a background border image. The bottom element is a background.

What I want to do is hollow out the middle element, so that I can see through the top element into the bottom element, but leave the border of the middle element surrounding the top element.

http://jsbin.com/unimux/4/edit

As you can see the middle element is blocking the view to the bottom element.

Edit: I did try using border-image but it wouldn't render correctly for me with border-radius.

Edit2: is it possible to get the desired effect with border-image? Kudos to anyone who can make it look not terrible with border-image.

Edit3: Some progress based on Zuul's answer:
http://jsbin.com/unimux/15/edit

Comment: Can you show what the end-result should look like? I can't help but feel there's a way (albeit probably not with 'hollowing' anything); unfortunately I'm not sure I understand what it is that you want as the question currently stands (it may have been a *very* long day at work, though...), sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a new element, with a class, e.g., `.apple` and place it over all other existent elements with the same image as the bottom one:

See your [JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/unimux/7/edit) Altered!

```
  div.apple {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(http://www.ipadwallpapersonly.com/images/wallpapers/1gk0rv4ng.jpg) center center;
  }
```

Having the image centred and by give a correct margin value, it simulates the "hollow" effect at the `div.middle`.

**See the result preview:**

[image: End Result Preview]

---

If the elements dimensions aren't the same, the use of CSS [position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position) helps keepping everything into the proper place:

An example [here](http://jsbin.com/unimux/12/edit)!

Comment: Well the problem is that'll make the border transparent too, which is not desirable.

Comment: Sorry I mean the middle element is the border. The point is to create an image border around the top element.

Comment: The issue is that I can still see the middle element through the top element, which is not desired.

Comment: @Harry, please see my updated answer with a solution to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, great idea! However I'm having some difficulty getting the images to match up because in my actual site the dimensions of the bottom and the overlay are different

Comment: @Harry Take a look at [this link](http://jsbin.com/unimux/12/edit), solves you dimensions issue!

Comment: Thanks but can't move the middle and the top. Need to manipulate the background-position of the `.apple` to match the empty space where it's positioned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12621/discussion-between-zuul-and-harry)

Comment: The reason for the aligning is `background-attachment fixed`. This fixes the background image relative to the viewport rather than the element. Good to know that this is proper behavior.

Comment: Yes, I saw that yesterday on the "live" URL ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that with the current state of CSS. Maybe just put the bottom element on top of the middle one, and work?

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion about moving the bottom element on top of the middle one.

Answer (score 1):

As per egasimus, you can't really do that with CSS.

Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzLM/) though, with four `div`s creating the 'window'.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, pretty hard to do it with rounded borders and images though. However it's not impossible, and if desperate enough. :D

Comment: If you mean border-radii (:D) on the inside, yeah, that's hard. But I've updated the fiddle with border-radii on the outside.